# Griffon dont create Eclipse .project and .classpath files

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, griffon

Griffon 0.9.2-beta-3

after exec "griffon create-app DemoConsole"
cant find the .project, so cant import it into eclipse(sts).

but the docs say that "Griffon automatically creates Eclipse .project and .classpath files for you",

did i miss some step?

---

solved by :

1. griffon integrate-with --eclipse
2. griffon install-plugin eclipse-support
3. griffon eclipse-update
4. eclipse --> import existing project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In STS 2.6 (& probably other Eclipse versions) also need to add a classpath variable.

If you get errors relating to 'unbound classpath variable' and the files concerned start with GRIFFON_HOME/....

```
Select Eclipse/STS -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables
New ... -> Add 'GRIFFON_HOME' and navigate to location of your Griffon installation.
```

Confirming this & a rebuild of proj. should clear the errors.

If you want to do this on a per project basis - just right click the project & follow the same procedure under Build Path -> Libraries

Comment: With latest versions of the eclipse-support plugin there's the need for another variable in your path -> IVY2_CACHE which should point to $USER_HOME/.ivy2/cache

Answer (score 4):

solved by :

- griffon integrate-with --eclipse
- griffon install-plugin eclipse-support
- griffon eclipse-update
- eclipse --> import existing project

Comment: ups for answering your own question. Nice 'n mate. (disclaimer - I don't usually work in Eclipse, so I can't verify the effectiveness of the fix. ymmv)