# Is there a simple way of adding griffon functionality to groovy?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, griffon

I've been learning about groovy and it works nicely with eclipse via the eclipse groovy plugin.  I've been informed that I should use griffon if I want to write desktop applications.

Is it possible to add libraries/jars/etc to my groovy install so that I can create griffon applications?  (I know that I could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533954/griffon-dont-create-eclipse-project-and-classpath-files) instead, but it doesn't really do what I want.)

Comment: No, you should install griffon to write griffon apps

Comment: Can you explain why or why my proposal is a bad idea?

Comment: Because there is no point in reinventing the wheel or trying to do one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Griffon is more than just a set of libraries, it's a full blown framework that provides a command line tool that takes care of many things, like processing resources, launching the application, packaging and deployment. It's also extensible via plugins. This being said, you cannot build a Griffon application with just its runtime libraries placed under ~/.groovy/lib